# Hostname reverts back to original name after reboot

Tags: linux

I have tried the following to set the hostname on my SUSE Linux 13.1 box to set the host name but nothing works and hostname keeps reverting back to original or old name.

I tried

```
hostnamectl set-hostname --static set-hostname new-host_fqdn
```

I made sure the `/etc/hostname` file gets updated with the new-host_fqdn and verified by

```
hostnamectl status
```

which displayed the new-host_fqdn. I modified the and added

```
#vi /etc/hosts 

192.168.1.5 short_name new-host_fqdn
```

I also made sure there are no old host name/s in

```
/etc/hosts or /etc/hostname
```

However after the reboot server name reverts back to the old name

I repeated the above and this time as final step issued the following command, reboot but same results

```
echo "new_host_fqdn" >> /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

I repeated the above steps and at the end issued below command which did not work either

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'kernel.hostname = NEW-HOST_FQDN' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
```

After reboot completed the above same issue - I tried the following including above steps

```
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg and changed "preserve_hostname" from "false" to "true"
```

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

I renamed the following but did not help

```
/etc/cloud directory to /etc/cloud_OLD
```

I removed the cloud-init package that did not resolve the issue, other packages cloud-initramfs-copymods cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf were not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Might be that network manager changes it. Check what network manager says and maybe change it there.

```
nmcli general hostname
nmcli general hostname new-host-name
```

Comment: Network Manager is not installed on the system

Comment: running `grep -r old_hostname / 2>/dev/null` revealed that the hostname was being configured via configuration files in `/opt/ws/`